# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException - Autowired Annotation is not working

Tags: spring

I am new to spring and I made a test program, which will connect to database and show the data accordingly.

However I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

This is my project structure:
[image]

**Error message:**

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [ex1-offers] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [ex1-offers] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


Root Cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ex1offersController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setOfferService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'offerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setOfferDAO' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'offerDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJdbc' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


Root Cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'offerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setOfferDAO' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'offerDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJdbc' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)


Root Cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'offerDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJdbc' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

**Web.xml**

I am using other spring bean configuration files, which is getting loaded by dispatcher servlet and i have mapped the dispatcher servlet to "/" url.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <display-name>ex1-offers</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/myoracle</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>ex1-offers</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ex1-offers</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/ex1-offers-servlet.xml
    classpath:org/ex1/offers/config/offerDAO-Config.xml
    classpath:org/ex1/offers/config/OfferService-config.xml
    </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ex1-offers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**ex1-offers-servlet.xml**

spring bean configuration file. component scan is set to the controller. I am using only one controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.ex1offers.controllers"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:resources location="/Resources/" mapping="/static/**"></mvc:resources>
    

    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/myoracle" id="dataSource"></jee:jndi-lookup>
</beans>
```

**offerDAO-Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.ex1.offers.DAO"></context:component-scan>
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/myoracle" id="dataSource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    </jee:jndi-lookup>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

**offerService-config.xml**
Spring bean config file for service class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.ex1.offers.service"></context:component-scan>
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/myoracle" id="dataSource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    </jee:jndi-lookup>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

**Ex1offersController.java**

```
package org.ex1offers.controllers;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.ex1.offers.DAO.Offer;
import org.ex1.offers.service.OfferService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Ex1offersController {

    private OfferService offerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setOfferService(OfferService offerService) {
        this.offerService = offerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public String create(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("offer", new Offer());
        return "createOffer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/doCreate")
    public String doCreate(Model model, @Valid Offer offer, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "createOffer";
        }
        return "Success";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/show")
    public ModelAndView create() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("showOffer");

        mv.addObject("offers", offerService.showOffer());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**OfferService.java**

```
package org.ex1.offers.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.ex1.offers.DAO.Offer;
import org.ex1.offers.DAO.OfferDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class OfferService {

    private OfferDAO offerDAO;
    
    @Autowired
    public void setOfferDAO(OfferDAO offerDAO) {
        this.offerDAO = offerDAO;
    }

    public List<Offer> showOffer() {
        return offerDAO.showOffer();
    }
}
```

**OfferDAO.java**

```
package org.ex1.offers.DAO;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("offerDAO")
public class OfferDAO {
    
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbc(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }
    
    public List<Offer> showOffer(){
        return jdbc.query("select * from offers", new RowMapper<Offer>() {
            @Override
            public Offer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Offer offer = new Offer();
                offer.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                offer.setId(rs.getString("name"));
                offer.setId(rs.getString("email"));
                offer.setId(rs.getString("text"));
                return offer; 
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is not autowired properly check you properly configue them

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have changed it and it's working fine.  @Autowired
 public void setJdbc(DataSource dataSource) {
  this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the full stack trace. Spring has really nice stacktrace and reading the whole trace and messages gives you a good understanding of what might be the issue.

Looking at the full trace, we see this message:
Root Cause

*org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: **Error creating bean with name 'offerDAO'**: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJdbc' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: **No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' available:** expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}*

It clearly mentions that it does not have a NamedParameterJDBCTemplate type Bean in the context and hence cannot Autowire.

You are using xml configurations along with Annotation support.
So you have to define a Configuration Class and define a Bean of the type NamedParameterJDBCTemplate, for Spring to instantiate the NamedParameterJDBCTemplate bean first.

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalBeanConfiguration {
 @Bean
 public NamedParameterJDBCTemplate namedParameterJDBCTemplate() {
   // instantiate your NamedParameterJDBCTemplate bean and return it.
 }
}
```

You are defining the Datasource bean in the xml file. It has been long I worked with xml configuration so I am not quite sure if you can @Autowide the dataSource into the Configuration class. Check on that, because your NamedParameterJDBCTemplate needs a DataSource.

If it works, you can autowire the Datasource you defined in your xml into your Configuration class.

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalBeanConfiguration {
   @Autowire
   private DataSource dataSource;
    
   @Bean("namedParameterJDBCTemplate") // Explicit name or else spring uses the method name as bean name
   public NamedParameterJDBCTemplate namedParameterJDBCTemplate() {
     return new NamedParameterJDBCTemplate(dataSource);
   }
}
```

You can also define your NamedParameterJDBCTemplate type bean in your xml.

```
<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate"   
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">  
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>  
</bean>
```

You mentioned new to Spring, I would recommend looking into and using Spring Boot. It removes most of the configurations and provides a default configuration OOTB, on top which you can customize your configurations.
Saying that, do you not need to know these injections and how IOC works with Spring, no you have to. SpringBoot is the project which just removes all these xml code and need of external webserver so that you face less issue bootstrapping the project and spend time learning or writing code.

Comment: Thanks Dey for the clear explanation. I have changed my code accordingly and it's working now. Have a nice day!

Comment: Np. You are welcome Wolfgang. I would suggest keeping these xmls and class configurations to bootstrap your project with Spring - config to bootstrap Hibernate/JbbcTemplate/Dispactcher Servlet in your github. I kept a working solution there because making it work in one go is real trouble. Once you understand the core concepts of DI, IOC, Autowire, Bean, Bean Scopes, bean id, bean name, just move to Springboot. Much more easy and painless !

Comment: Btw did you Autowire the DS or defined the Template in the xml? I want to know if the Autowire works.

Comment: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate was not autowired properly in the offerDAO. I changed it below. @Autowired
 public void setJdbc(DataSource dataSource) {
  this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }

Comment: Nice, so autowire works, means the xml config is read and loaded before the Config class is run. Makes sense that will be the flow, since Spring needs to know if you have enabled annotations in the xml. And we write new ConfigurableContext(xml file).

Comment: Thanks Priyak, I will definitely move to springboot once I understand core concepts. However I am struggling a lot to understand as Spring is completely new to me.